# Different CMU Serif Greek font after updating MikTex

Tags: fonts, fontspec, greek

I used to have the old MikTex Launcher and I updated it recently to the newest version. I noticed today that the CMU Serif font I used has changed and it is considerably thinner. I'd appreciate any help on why it's happening.

Before updating:
[image: Old]

After updating:
[image]

MWE (compiled with Xelatex and unchanged before and after the update)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xgreek,polyglossia}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{CMU Serif} 
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\begin{document}
    {Ασκήσεις Μαθηματικών Α' Γυμνασίου} \\
    \rule[2ex]{\textwidth}{2pt}
    
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item 
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Πόσες μέρες έχει η εβδομάδα;
            \item Ποια είναι η τρίτη μέρα της εβδομάδας; (Αν θεωρηθεί σαν πρώτη μέρα η Κυριακή)
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

pdffonts results:
Before updating:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub
uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- ---
--- ---------
NTGYGX+CMUSerif-Roman-Identity-H     CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes
yes      6  0
DIOZJR+LatinModernMath-Regular-Identity-H CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes
 yes yes      8  0
```

After updating:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub
uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- ---
--- ---------
AVIBFO+CMUSerif-Roman                CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes
yes      6  0
YSIIOF+LatinModernMath-Regular-Identity-H CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes
 yes yes      8  0
```

Comment: Which viewer did you use to make these screenshots? Do you observe the same effect in other viewers (Sumatra, Adobe Reader, etc)? Does it occur on different zoom levels?

Comment: @Marijn I have thinked the same of your comment. Adobe Reader, recently, it has been updates.

Comment: @Marijn You are probably correct. I used Adobe Reader for these screenshots. I tried the pdf viewer from Chrome and they seem they same. On an online pdf viewer I observe the same effect.

Comment: what does the pdffonts utility  (or acrobat font menu) report for the fonts in the two pdfs?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've updated the post with the pdffonts results.

Comment: well so it's not a viewer issue (or at least not just that) you are using different fonts, changed from "True Type" to "Type 0C" which is using PostScript rather than TrueType font paths internally.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you have any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: no. well it's the map files for CMU but they are normally installed by default and I don't know how miktex config works as I don't use it and I'm not sure if miktex distributes the fonts in both forms (so you could just change the map file) or if it only distributes it in the CID C0 form now so going back would involve installing fonts. Some knowledgable miktex user will be able to help now the issue is identified though.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for identifying the issue, I'll see if I can find something by googling.

Comment: I get type 0C fonts on miktex and I don't think that there was an update that would change this. Add `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1 ` to your document. Then compile with `xelatex --no-pdf file`  and `xdvipdfmx -vv file.xdv` and check the absolute font pathes in the output and in the log.

Comment: After removing + adding libraries, I found that the command "\setmainfont{CMU Serif} " changes the font type from Type0C to TrueType. Can I find somewhere a Type0C version of this font?